# How to find all words that have one (or more) blank space(s) in them in Notepad++?

Tags: search, text, notepad++, space

This is a sample, all lines have been trimmed leading and trailing spaces.

> word word
>   
> word word word
>   
> word word word word
>   
> word

Result would be

> word word

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your question.  Your post is going to get downvotes from a [lack of effort](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt) and/or a [lack of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode) if you don't provide for us something to work with.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to write Notepad++ in my question. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: What are the criterias to select `word word` but not `word word word`? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52564651/edit) and add more informations.

Comment: For me a word with spaces inside it is not a word but multiple words.

Comment: As I asked, I need to find words that have ONE blank space in them.

Comment: "For me a word with spaces inside it is not a word but multiple words." 
Maybe I should ask how to mark lines contain ONE blank space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find lines that just have one space (with some 'word' before and after), try with this:

`^\S+ \S+$`

Explained:

```
^        # Begin of line
  \S+    # non-blank character repeated 1 or more times
  [ ]    # a space (I'm using [ ] to make it more clear)
  \S+    # non-blank character repeated 1 or more times
$        # end of line
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3gAiZx/4/)**